# Break and continue in a while loop

Tags: php

**Problem**

Basically I have got a game where 2 teams are competing with each other. With first while loop I get those team names and information. In the second loop I am fetching username/members who are participating in those teams and then run a query to fetch their records.

The final while loop I have used to Some up the teams calculation, i.e. if Team A have 2 players named as **Joe and Mike** and Team B have 3 players named as **John,Jack and Dave** So for Team A Joe did ran 5 km and Mike ran 7 km which brings up to a **total of 12 km for team A**. Likewise for team B John ran 11km, Jack did 2 km and Dave did 1km which makes a **total of 14km for team B**. But because of this loop is shows **Team A = 12km** and **Team B = 26km**. It will be great if anyone can guide me through to where I might be going wrong.

**Code**

```
    $t_name = "Joe Running8 Vs Mike Running2";
    $sql_team = 'SELECT * FROM teams WHERE t_name="'.$t_name.'" AND game_type = "Activity"';
    $result_team = mysql_query($sql_team) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalNoUsers = '';
    $activityTotal = '';
    $avgPP = '';

    //Table structure for displaying the results    
    echo '<table border="1" align="center" width="100%">';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>Team Name</th>';
            echo '<th>Total no Activity</th>';
            echo '<th>Total Users</th>';
            echo '<th>Avg per User</th>';
            echo '<th>Avg %</th>';
        echo '</tr>';

    while($row_team = mysql_fetch_array($result_team)){
        $sql_SelUsers = 'SELECT * FROM teams where t_name="'.$row_team['team'].'"';
        echo $sql_SelUsers."<hr>";
        $result_SelUsers = mysql_query($sql_SelUsers) or die(mysql_error());
        $totalNoUsers = mysql_num_rows($result_SelUsers);

        while($row_SU = mysql_fetch_array($result_SelUsers)){
            //$accepted_on = "30/01/2013";
            $userA = explode("/","27/01/2014");
            $accepted_on = mktime(0,0,0, $userA[1],$userA[0],$userA[2]);
            $date_time_compare = date('D, j M Y H:i:s', $accepted_on);

            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_feeds where username="'.$row_SU['username'].'" AND gadget_data_type= "Activity" and gadget_name = "'.$row_SU['gadget_type'].'" and gadget_sub_data_type = "'.$row_SU['game_parameter'].'" and STR_TO_DATE( date_time,  "%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s" ) >= STR_TO_DATE( "'.$date_time_compare.'",  "%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s" ) ORDER BY df_id DESC';

            $result_df = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            echo $row_SU['username']."<br />";

          /****** Here is the problem ********/
            while($row_df = mysql_fetch_array($result_df)){
                $activityTotal += $row_df['gadget_data_type_value'];
                echo "<br /><strong>".$activityTotal."</strong><br />";
            }   
        }//end while query data_feeds

        echo "TnP-> ".$totalNoUsers;
        $activityTotal = $activityTotal/1000;
        $avgPP = ($activityTotal/$totalNoUsers);
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row_team['challToTeam'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.number_format($activityTotal, 2, '.', ',').'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$totalNoUsers.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.number_format($avgPP, 2, '.', ',').'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$totalNoUsers.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
    }//end while query Teams

    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `$activityTotal` before your loop.
After the first loop its value is 12 km, and
then you add 14 km to it, which becomes 26km instead of 14 km .

Correction:

```
    $activeTotal = 0   // RESET TO ZERO 
    while($row_df = mysql_fetch_array($result_df)){
        $activityTotal += $row_df['gadget_data_type_value'];
        echo "<br /><strong>".$activityTotal."</strong><br />";
    }
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Forgot to pre define the varible. Thanks alot !!

Comment: Then you can accept this as correct answer by checking the tick mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$activityTotal set to empty or 0 before next team total start
//use

$activityTotal = 0; //init to 0 before loop
```